# To cast a numpy array from bool to int, should I multiply by one or use astype(int)?

Tags: python, numpy

`bool_array * 1` and `bool_array.astype(int)` appear to do the same thing. Which is more efficient?

Comment: Questions like this really need to define what they mean by "better". I would say that *idiomatically* to create a new array of a different dtype, you should use `.astype`, note, the terminology "cast" here is ambiguous. So again, you really need to provide some more details

Comment: Another reason to favor `astype` is that the intent is clearer.  The multiplication depends on numpy's coercion rules.  It works but the intent isn't as clear.

Comment: I changed the question from "better" to "more efficient"

Answer (score 1):

`bool_array.astype(int)` is faster ([Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Sz73GZuBhNObnW700K6YQTg31O4YHQ4h#scrollTo=Jj0iMI6MdMJw)):

```
import numpy as np

bool_array = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1_000_000).astype(bool)
```

```
%timeit int_array = bool_array * 1
```

> 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.5 ms per loop

```
%timeit int_array = bool_array.astype("int")
```

> 1000 loops, best of 5: 973 µs per loop